# Puzzling behavior of arrange_at with .funs

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't understand what `dplyr::arrange_at` is doing when passed a `.funs` parameter.

For example suppose we create a data frame `Z`:

```
library(dplyr)
Z <- expand.grid(A = c(1:2, NA), B = c(1:2, NA))
```

and suppose we want to sort it by `A` (with `NA` *first*) and then by `B`. Then we might try `target` or `current` below:

```
all_equal(
  target = Z %>% arrange(!is.na(A), A, B),
  current = Z %>% arrange_at(.vars = c("A", "A", "B"), 
                             .funs = list(function(x)!is.na(x), identity, identity)),
  ignore_row_order = FALSE)
```

which returns "Same row values, but different order". The first version (`target`) is what I expected, but the second (`current`) is puzzling. What I expected is that each function in `.funs` would be applied to the corresponding column in `.var` and then it would be sorted much like `arrange()`.

Ultimately I want to sort in a very dynamic way and hence want the full power of `arrange_at`.

### Update

As [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271) says in a comment, the `_at` family of `dplyr` functions create the Cartesian product of all `.vars` and all `.funs`.  Therefore what I need is an `arrange_parallel_at` function that expects `.vars` and `.funs` to have the same length and where the kth function is evaluated on the column whose name is the kth entry in `.vars` (and only that column). Then all these columns in the same order become the argument to `arrange`.

Comment: Issue is that `arrange_at` like other tidyverse `at` functions applies aech of the function to all the columns.  If you need to apply separately, try `Z %>% arrange(!is.na(A), !!! rlang::syms(names(.)))`

Comment: @akrun so `!!! rlang::syms(names(.))` in effect appends `A,B` to the call. In this minimal example it suffices, but what I need is something more dynamic; e.g. I have a character vector of column names and a list of transformations (e.g., `desc` or `identity`) I want to apply to each of them, and then use that to `arrange()`.

Comment: Yes, think of `names(.)` as the character vector, i dont see any issue in having to use a veector

Answer (score 0):

Below is *an* answer to my own question. While it works (and in particular does what I asked in the Update) it's almost certainly sub-optimal since I suspect there are better solutions based on [tidy eval](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org).
Therefore I'm reluctant to accept it.

```
library(tidyverse)

arrange_parallel_at <- function(.data, .vars, .funs) {
  stopifnot(length(.vars) == length(.funs), is.character(.vars), is.list(.funs))

  tmp_cols <- paste0('.tmp', seq_along(.vars))
  for (i in seq_along(.vars)) {
    .data[[tmp_cols[i]]] <- sort_trans[[i]](.data[[.vars[i]]])
  }

  .data <- arrange_at(.data, tmp_cols)
  .data[tmp_cols] <- NULL
  .data
}
```

Below is some test code.

```
tibble(A = c(1:2, NA)) %>%
  crossing(B = c(1:2, NA)) ->
  Z

na_first <- function(x) !is.na(x)

all_equal(
  Z %>% arrange(!is.na(A), A, !is.na(B), desc(B)),
  Z %>% arrange_parallel_at(   c(     'A',      'A',      'B',  'B'), 
                            list(na_first, identity, na_first, desc)),
  ignore_row_order = FALSE) # returns TRUE
```